# Update row with multiple row in another table Error : ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, plsql

I have Table A with 1 row and wanted to update it from another table (which has 3 rows for it and I can take any one of them).

```
Table A
-----------
TrnID | trn_Status
 2345 | null
 9876 | null
 9878 | null

Table B
-----------
TrnID | trn_Status
 2345 | 2
 2345 | 2
 2345 | 2
 9876 | 4
 9876 | 4
 9878 | 2
```

I am facing error when i try to do something like this

```
UPDATE TableA tabA
SET    ( tabA.trn_status ) = (
                            SELECT trn_status 
                            FROM   TableB tabB 
                            WHERE  ( 
                                        tabA.trn_id = tabB.trn_id                                   
                                    )                                   
                         ) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

Since there are several rows in the result you need to decide which one to use as the new value for `trn_status`:

- Limit your subquery with `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY`.
- If you can guarantee that all corresponding records are full duplicates, use `DISTINCT`.
- Using `min`, `max`, `avg` aggregate would be other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found out, thanks for help

```
UPDATE TableA tabA 
SET ( tabA.trn_Status ) = ( 
                            SELECT distinct trn_Status 
                            FROM TableB tabB 
                            WHERE ( tabA.trn_id = tabB.trn_id ) and rownum = 1 
                          ) ;
```